# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member

Tags: c#, serialization, remoting

I have written a piece of code that loads DLL-files from disk on demand and then unloads them when a client has finished using them. The idea is that those DLLs are implementing an interface known to the client and the client can use them as plugins.

Everything seemed fine in my first tests until I created a second "plugin". The second plugin is identical with my first test case, yet I get a System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException. Below you see my class that I can resolve.

```
namespace ResolverTest.TestController1
{
    using System;

    ...

    [Serializable]
    public class TestController1 : IProductController
    {
        public IProductConfigurationValidationResult ValidateProductConfiguration(ProductConfiguration productConfiguration)
        {
            var result = new ProductConfigurationValidationResult();
            result.Success = true;
            return result;
        }

        public IPerformanceCreationResult CreateProductConfigurationPerformance(ProductConfiguration productConfiguration)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the class that it cannot resolve.

```
namespace ResolverTest2.TestController2
{
    using System;

    ...

    [Serializable]
    public class TestController2 : IProductController
    {
        public IProductConfigurationValidationResult ValidateProductConfiguration(ProductConfiguration productConfiguration)
        {
            var result = new ProductConfigurationValidationResult();
            result.Success = true;
            return result;
        }

        public IPerformanceCreationResult CreateProductConfigurationPerformance(ProductConfiguration productConfiguration)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The exact exception I get says:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type i
>   s not resolved for member 'ResolverTest2.TestController2.TestController2,Resolve
>   rTest2.TestController2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Note that both classes are public, so there is no problem accessing them. My class that handles the loading of the DLLs into an appdomain inherits MarshalByRefObject so that part is also properly defined. It seems like there is something different between TestController1 and TestController2. The .net versions are the same and I even checked the assembly info. They do not have different dependencies than each other and the reference list is exactly the same for both of them. Last but not least, the class that resolves the DLLs is checking that the path passed is correct, otherwise it throws and exception.

What else should I look at?

Comment: There is something wrong with the ResolverTest2.TestController2.dll assembly.  Maybe you copied it by hand and forgot to update it when you changed the code.  Show the trace you get from Fulogvw.exe (log all binds) if that doesn't help.  Do strongly avoid inventing your own plugin architecture, you never want to do it this way.  It has been done.

Comment: @HansPassant I did not copy anything by hand. I have cleaned the project to be sure and even deleted it and started over again. What plugin architecture would you suggest for loading DLLs on demand and then unloading them after usage?

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, I found out what was going on. I had accidentally added a reference to ResolverTest.TestController1 in the client project. It was finding the DLL in the bin-map and therefore it was loading it. However, I don not want to have the files in the bin map. I need to have them in any folder I want and load them from the disk. I need to figure out how to do that.